# No "Disable Analytics" setting for Quantcast Measurement

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, terms-of-service

In iPhone → Settings → Stack Exchange → Notices → Quantcast Measurement, it says, near the end:

> If you would like to learn more or **opt out of such data collection**, please use the **Disable Analytics** setting.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Where's the "Disable Analytics" setting? I can't find it.

I tried the "Disable Metrics" setting, but it only disabled calls to Google Analytics and `/1/track/ios` of mobile.stackexchange.com. The calls to m.quantcount.com are still there, even after I restarted the app.

Version: Stack Exchange iOS App Version 0.1.50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, thanks for catching that.  The 'Disable Metrics' setting should kill everything.  I'll also update the Quantcast notice to match the label.  Should be fixed in the next build (0.1.51+).

**Update**: while working on this I also noticed that opting out of GA or QC was only going to take effect after the app restarted, so now I've updated it to take effect immediately.

Comment: Verified fixed in v0.1.54.