# What is Metrics setting in iPad app used for?

Tags: discussion, ios-app, ipad

What is the Metrics setting in the iPad app used for?

[image]

Is it meter, kilogram, etc? What happens if I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means opting out of data collection, as mentioned in [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229916/no-disable-analytics-setting-for-quantcast-measurement) and its answer.

So, whatever stats Stack Exchange collects about the app users, if this setting is turned on (i.e. metrics disabled), you won't be part of it.

Comment: *data collection... whatever stats Stack Exchange collects about the app users* ... so it can still be my height and weight? Is that data then used so Stack Exchange can forward the weight-loss pills/diet spam?

Comment: @rene might be, but more likely stats like what questions you visited.

Comment: So if I want to let them collect the stat, I should switch the button off? Will it slow the app or the iPad?

Comment: @Ooker as for slowing down I doubt it, it just means sending data silently, the app is not waiting for a response. And yes, leaving this turned off should let them collect data about your app usage.